# Crontab not working for JAR file

Tags: ubuntu, jar, cron

I am trying to execute a JAR file periodically (let's say every 10 minutes) in an Ubuntu environment. For that purpose, I am using the crontab command.

```
crontab -e
# m h  dom mon dow   command
1 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar /home/vadmin/Desktop/executable.jar
```

I am using absolute paths, and the .jar has execution permissions. I don't know why it is not working. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Am I using crontab in an incorrect way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: i don't know if this is the issue, but for every 10 minutes execution you should put 0/10 * * * *. your example shall execute every hour at 1st minute.

Comment: Redirect output to a file by adding `>/path/to/logfile 2>&1` to the end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, my crontab wasn't correct. Now that I want to execute my command every 15 minutes, in the m(minutes) field, I have to specify in which minutes of every hour the command must be executed. For example:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0,15,30,45 * * * * /usr/bin/java -jar /home/vadmin/Desktop/executable.jar > /home/vadmin/Desktop/log.txt 2>&1
```

With this command, my command will be executed at 2:00, 2:15, 2:30, 2:45, 3:00, 3:15 and so on.

Also it is importante the redirection of the output.

```
2>&1
```

With this, I am able to redirect the STDERR output, to the same file than the STDOUT.

Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: 0/15 * * * * will provide you the same effect actually.